# How to trigger an event after a Chrome extension popup is displayed?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am using jQuery with a Google Chrome extension popup. The pop-up page uses jQuery's 'document.ready' event to trigger a request to a web service. The problem is that the pop-up does not render until a response is received, which makes it seem unresponsive. Here's an outline of the page:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./plugin.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            plugin.init();            
            plugin.getData();
        });        
    </script>
</head>
<body>...</body>
</html>
```

Is there an event I can use to trigger 'getData()' *after* Chrome renders the pop-up? I have tried monkeying with visibility events of divs within the body, but I haven't been able to trigger these events automatically other than by handling document.ready, which leads to the same behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `setTimeout` with no delay:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./plugin.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            plugin.init();            
            setTimeout(plugin.getData);
        });        
    </script>
</head>
<body>...</body>
</html>
```

I've done this in an extension of my own, and it should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could interact with the background page to fetch data asynchronously:

```
plugin.init()

chrome.extension.sendRequest({fetch: true}, function(response) {
  plugin.handleData(response);
});
```

Background:

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.fetch){
    sendResponse(getData());
  }
});
```